# How to Deal with Bold Red 'Deceptive Site Ahead' Warning on Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, malware, phishing

I have dev.randomlog.org which serves as a repository for many of my tests as a developer. It's up for over a decade (nearly two I think), but...

3 days ago, the notorious big red warning covers everything inside. Search console shows N/A in the sample URL, and `http://dev.randomlog[.]org/` in "related messages"

This is quite frustrating since I had shared a few links from that domain with a prospective client.

I'm pretty certain there's no 'hack' going on as suggested by some links in the big red page. I am more inclined to believe that Google think I'm a phisher because there are forms on that domain that are now being used on other websites.

I Googled but have not yet found any solid information on how to resolve this issue.

I post here in hoping:

1. Someone can provide another insight.
2. If my guess about phishing 'accusation' is correct, what should I do next? Putting ethics aside, is it dangerous (as we can be accused of phishing by THE GOOGLE) to leave some forms that are identical with other site's form in our site?

--

Bonus problem: I tried posting the exact same text above in Google Search Console Community forum but it said: Failed to post. Content violates Community Policy.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a programming problem. It might be on topic for https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Check your website for malware and unwanted software (it is probably just a false positive but it's good to check your website hasn't been tampered with by someone that isn't you), removing any malicious code or files (If you find any), and requesting a review from Google (you can do that here https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35843?hl=en). If your website doesn't have the warning anymore then you don't have to take any action.

I hope this helps!